# Creating triggers without SUPER privilege

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create a trigger in a MySQL database. However, I'm not allowed to:

> #1419 - You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

However, I can't enable said variable either, because I need the SUPER privilege for that too...

I've been looking for solutions for hours, but I cannot get it to work. I have tried the following to add the super privilege:

`GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO user@'...' IDENTIFIED BY '...';`

Result:

> #1045 - Access denied for user '...'@'%' (using password: YES)

In terms of configuration files: It seems like I can only view the config.inc.php file. I cannot edit it either:

> Cannot load or save configuration
>   Please create web server writable folder config in phpMyAdmin top level directory as described in documentation. Otherwise you will be only able to download or display it.

What am I expected to do?

Comment: You should use the `root` user to grant `SUPER` privilege.

Comment: @Barmar is right, if could don't have `root` access, contact your DBA.